# Change [ecuador-citizen] to [ecuador-citizens]

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging

I created the [ecuador-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuador-citizen) instead of [ecuador-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuador-citizens), can someone with powers fix this please.

Comment: Thanks for the notification, I just changed it. Imho it takes some time until the changes are visible.

Comment: Thank you @RoflcoptrException

Comment: I know this is old, but should it be ecuadorian-citizens? It wouldn't be america-citizens.